# Faraday - test a connection

Tags: ruby, faraday

I'm working with a connection object with Faraday in Ruby. That said, sometimes the target server is down, which results in a pretty ugly ruby error. Is there a way use Faraday to test existence of a connection before risking error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faraday throws specific errors in case of connection problems.

https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/blob/master/lib/faraday/error.rb

I suggest to add error handling to your code:

```
def do_my_network_stuff
  #making_requests
rescue Faraday::Error #or more specific error type 
  #handling_errors
end
```